# code stopping after opening a video or file

Tags: python, encoding, artificial-intelligence

i am working on a small ai that opens files and is able to search youtube etc
but it stops the code after it opens anything
see code below

```
listener = sr.Recognizer()
engine = pyttsx3.init()
voices = engine.getProperty('voices')
engine.setProperty('voice', voices[1].id)


def talk(text):
    engine.say(text)
    engine.runAndWait()


def take_command():
    try:
        with sr.Microphone() as source:
            print('listening...')
            voice = listener.listen(source)
            command = listener.recognize_google(voice)
            command = command.lower()
            if 'jarvis' in command:
                command = command.replace('jarvis', '')
                print(command)
    except:
        pass
    return command


def run_jarvis():
    command = take_command()
    if 'play' in command:
        song = command.replace('play', '')
        talk('playing ' + song)
        pywhatkit.playonyt(song)
    elif 'time' in command:
        time = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%I:%M %p')
        talk('Current time is ' + time)
    elif 'who is' in command:
        person = command.replace('who is', '')
        info = wikipedia.summary(person, 1)
        print(info)
        talk(info)
    elif 'joke' in command:
        talk(pyjokes.get_joke())
    elif 'open twitch' in command:
        search = command.replace('open twitch','https://www.twitch.tv/toasted_gg/')
        talk('opening your twitch')
        wb.open('https://www.twitch.tv/toasted_gg/')
    elif 'search'in command:
        search = command.replace ('search', '')
        pywhatkit.search(search)
    elif 'exit' in command:
        talk("Thanks for giving me your time")
        exit()
    elif 'who made you' in command:
        talk("i was made by 5 8 4 6")
    elif 'open minecraft' in command:
        subprocess.call('C:\Program Files\Feather Launcher\Feather Launcher.exe')
        talk('opening minecraft')
    elif 'open discord' in command:
        os.startfile('')
        talk('opening discord')

    else:
        talk('Please say the command again.')


while True:
    run_jarvis()
```

i didnt try anything yet
and i dont know what is wrong with the code, as far as my coding knowledge goes it should work just fine but it doesnt

Comment: Please [edit] your question to improve your [mcve]. In particular, share e.g. what are `sr` or `pyttsx3`, and how do you call your script and (full trace) error, if any…

Answer (score 0):

`subprocess.call` will wait for the command to complete before returning the return code, for example if you open Minecraft your program will be blocked until you close Minecraft.

You can use `subprocess.Popen` instead.